# Java remove escape characters from string

Tags: java

I have a string `"http:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/0vxOhd4qlnA\/maxresdefault.jpg"`.

I want it like `"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/0vxOhd4qlnA/maxresdefault.jpg"`.

I tried almost everything available on stackoverflow to remove backslash or escape character, but nothing is working.
I tried :

```
1) .replace("\\","")
2) .replaceAll("\\","")
3) .replace("\\\\/","/")
4) .replaceAll("\\\\/","/")
```

Thanks in advance!
Manali

Comment: "I tried almost everything [...]" => And these attempts must be part of your questions. Otherwise, it is off-topic!

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you building the http string you can do as follows

```
System.out.println(httpString.replace('\\', '/'));
```

or if you want to get the http address from user use

```
        String httpString = "";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.print( "Enter the improper URL: " );
        httpString = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(newString.replace('\\', '/'));
```